# Kubernetes ingress to pod running on same host?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

We are just getting started with k8s (bare metal on Ubuntu 20.04). Is it possible for ingress traffic arriving at a host for a load balanced service to go to a pod running on that host (if one is available)?

We have some apps that use client side consistent hashing (using customer ID) to select a service instance to call. The service instances are stateless but maintain in memory ML models for each customer. So it is useful (but not essential) to have repeated requests for a given customer go to the same service. Then we can just use antiAffinity to have one pod per host.

Our existing service discovery mechanism lets the clients find all the instances of the service and the nodes they are running on. All our k8s nodes are running the Nginx ingress controller.

Comment: check out https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this figured out. This was way harder than it should be IMO! **Update: It's not working. Traffic frequently goes to the wrong pod.**

The service needs `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` (see [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip)).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: starterservice
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: starterservice
  ports:
    - port: 8168
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

The Ingress needs `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"` ([service-upstream docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#service-upstream)).

The `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias: "~^starterservice-[a-z0-9]+\\.example\\.com"` bit is because our service discovery updates DNS so each instance of the service includes the name of the host it is running on in its DNS name.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: starterservice
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias: "~^starterservice-[a-z0-9]+\\.example\\.com"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host:  starterservice.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: starterservice
                port:
                  number: 8168
```

So now a call `https://starterservice-foo.example.com` will go to the instance running on k8s host foo.

Comment: Update: It's not working. Traffic frequently goes to the wrong pod.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Sticky Sessions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/) is what you are looking for. Ingress does not communicate directly with pods, but with services. Sticky sessions try to bind requests from the same client to the same pod by setting an affinity cookie.

This is used for example with SignalR sessions, where the negotiation request has to be on the same host as the following websocket connection.

Example:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: persistent
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

Affinity mode "balanced" is the default. If your pod count does not change, part of your clients will lose the session. Use "persistent" to have users connect to the same pod always (unless it dies of course). Further reading: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5944

Comment: The problem is that the incoming calls are all coming from the same IP. So the distribution is effectively decided by the payload (customer ID) not caller. So I don't think setting a cookie will work for this use-case.

Comment: We have quite a few related use-cases. We have stateless services that share out message queues between all instances. Each instance has a dashboard showing what is happening with their set of queues. So we need to be able to switch between instances (pods) somehow. The web UI currently has links to all instances for this.

Comment: hm ok, that's more complicated. how is the customer id passed, headers/path/body/cookie?

Comment: It's in the body. We could change things to have it somewhere else. At the moment the client is selecting the instance: It has the host and the pod name and anything else that might help can be provided via service discovery. If we can solve this we can put a lot of our infrastructure into k8s very quickly because legacy and k8s stuff will interop seamlessly.